# Why are these two non-English strings (with exactly the same appearance) different in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I'm reading a csv file by Pandas `pd.read_csv`. I want to remove all columns but `Mã NPP`. However, the string `Mã NPP` I input from keyboard is not the same as the one in the column names of the dataframe. As such, I could not subset the dataframe. I guess this problem is due to how non-English characters are encoded.

Could you elaborate how to make the string I input from keyboard "identical" to that from the dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/data/main/DIST_INVOICE_RETURN.csv', encoding = 'utf8', header = 0, nrows = 1)
x = 'Mã NPP'
y = df.columns[0]
print(x, '\n', y)
x == y
```

The result is

```
Mã NPP 
 Mã NPP
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right. Consider these two characters:

```py
a = "ã"
b = "ã"
print(a == b)
print(len(a), len(b))
print(list(a), list(b))
```

output:

```
False
1 2
['ã'] ['a', '̃']
```

looked similar but they are not equal to each other.

This is happening because these two strings use **different unicode encodings** to define each character.

```py
import unicodedata
a = "ã"
b = "ã"
print([unicodedata.name(c) for c in a])
print([unicodedata.name(c) for c in b])
```

output:

```
['LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE']
['LATIN SMALL LETTER A', 'COMBINING TILDE']
```

You can even see this in *Decomposition* field of :
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E3

To avoid this you need to do something called [**unicode normalization**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

> Return the normal form form for the Unicode string unistr. Valid
> values for form are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.
>
> The Unicode standard defines various normalization forms of a Unicode
> string, based on the definition of canonical equivalence and
> compatibility equivalence. In Unicode, several characters can be
> expressed in various way. For example, the character U+00C7 (LATIN
> CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA) can also be expressed as the sequence
> U+0043 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C) U+0327 (COMBINING CEDILLA).

After that you can compare them without problem:

```py
import unicodedata

a = "ã"
b = "ã"
normalized_a = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", a)
normalized_b = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", b)
print(normalized_a, normalized_b)
print(normalized_a == normalized_b)
```

So maybe you want to create your own function and wrap this helper function and use it instead of `==`:

```py
import unicodedata

a = "Mã NPP"
b = "Mã NPP"
print(list(a))
print(list(b))

def compare_strings(s1, s2):
    s1_normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", s1)
    s2_normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", s2)
    return s1_normalized == s2_normalized

print(a == b)
print(compare_strings(a, b))
```

output:

```
['M', 'ã', ' ', 'N', 'P', 'P']
['M', 'a', '̃', ' ', 'N', 'P', 'P']
False
True
```

**CopyRight**: This example was from [this article](https://github.com/fbaptiste/python-blog/blob/main/2022/07%20-%20July/case-insensitive-string-comparisons.ipynb). The writer took one step further and did a case-insensitive comparison between strings in case you are interested.

Comment: An addendum, I am assuming it is a Vietnamese language dataframe, in which case "Mã" may be NFD, or it might be a mixed format. Some input frameworks when typing Vietnamese use precomposed characters for the vowels and combining diacritics for the tones.